# How to insert an "Optimizer hint" to Hibernate criteria api query

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate, criteria

i have a hibernate query that is dynamically put together using the criteria api.
it generates queries that are unbearably slow, if executed as-is.

but i have noted they are about 1000% faster if I prepend /*+ FIRST_ROWS(10) */ to the query. how can i do this with the criteria api?

i tried criteria.setComment(..), but this seems to be ignored.

in the hibernate docs, 3.4.1.7. Query hints are mentioned, but it clearly states: "Note that these are not SQL query hints"

the result of the query will be paginated, so in 99% of the cases i will display the results 1-10.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could modify the optimizer mode at the session level:

```
ALTER SESSION SET optimizer_mode = FIRST_ROWS;
```

Either just before your query and then putting it back to its default value (`ALL_ROWS`) or in your case since 99% of the queries would benefit from it you could modify it at the schema level (with an `ON LOGON` trigger for exemple) or even at the instance level (modify the init parameter).

Comment: Can i do this setting for hibernate session factory?

Answer (score 10):

I have another generic solution, that should work for every Criteria query :
use a standard comment and an Hibernate Interceptor changing the ultimate SQL to the database.
(I used it with Hibernate 3.3, but should be useable for every version, registering of the Interceptor may be different.)

In your query code use:

```
criteria.setComment("$HINT$ push_pred(viewAlias)");
```

Write an Interceptor to change to SQL text (this one uses commons.lang3.StringUtils):

```
public class HibernateEntityInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {

@Override
public String onPrepareStatement(String sql) {
    if (sql.startsWith("/* $HINT$")) {
        String hintText = StringUtils.substringBetween(sql, "/* $HINT$", "*/");
        sql = sql.replaceFirst("select ", "select /*+" + hintText + "*/ ");
    }
    return sql;
}
```

Above is for Oracle, but should be easily adjustable for every DBMS.
Maybe you can/should create a constant for the hint marker "$HINT$".
Logging should be done, too (so you can easily see the correct calling of the Interceptor), I left it out above for simplicity.

The Interceptor must be registered. In Spring this is done in `applicationContext.xml`:

```
<bean id="entityListener" class="your.package.HibernateEntityInterceptor"/>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="entityInterceptor" ref="entityListener"/>
    [...]
```

Or (copy from the Hibernate 3.3 docs):

> A Session-scoped interceptor is specified when a session is opened
>   using one of the overloaded SessionFactory.openSession() methods
>   accepting an Interceptor.
>
> `Session session = sf.openSession( new HibernateEntityInterceptor() );`
>
> A SessionFactory-scoped interceptor is registered with the
>   Configuration object prior to building the SessionFactory. Unless a
>   session is opened explicitly specifying the interceptor to use, the
>   supplied interceptor will be applied to all sessions opened from that
>   SessionFactory. SessionFactory-scoped interceptors must be thread
>   safe. Ensure that you do not store session-specific states, since
>   multiple sessions will use this interceptor potentially concurrently.
>
> `new Configuration().setInterceptor( new HibernateEntityInterceptor() );`

Answer (score 7):

I was able to put in a Oracle hint by a adding a ProjectionList to the criteria.

```
ProjectionList proList = Projections.projectionList();
proList.add(Projections.sqlProjection("/*+INDEX_DESC(this_ MY_INDEX_NAME)*/ 1 as MYHINT",
    new String[]{},
    new Type[]{}));
//add properties from your class
proList.add(Projections.property("field1"));
proList.add(Projections.property("field2"));
proList.add(Projections.property("field3"));
c.setProjection(proList);
```

`c.list()` returns `List<Object[]>` in order of ProjectionList

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the hint syntax is not a comment, it just looks a bit like one.  It really has to go between the `SELECT` and the selected columns, whereas `setComment()` prepends the comment before the `SELECT`.

Beyond that, there are no silver bullets.  `FIRST_ROWS` is not a performance enhancing tool.  It may end up taking longer to get *all* the rows back.  Of course, in a user-facing program retrieving the first ten rows may be all we need to do.

But, which ever way you bounce it, if you want to use Oracle's hint syntax you'll need to go down the Native SQL route.

What else can you do?  I don't (yet) have much experience tuning Hibernate.  The one time I have under such a task the query was grabbing rows from a whole bunch of tables to instantiate an object with lots of sub-types.  Each sub-type was a separate table.  The query generated by Hibernate had many OUTER JOINs, which confused the heck out the optimizer.  Breaking that monster into several focused queries (one per sub-type) which used only INNER JOINs produced a two hundredfold reduction in retrieval time.

This may not be of any immediate use to you.  But the principle is, look at the Hibernate query and see whether it can be implemented in a different, more efficient way.

Comment: the result will indeed be user-faced.

Comment: the query itself is correct the way it is. since it is generated dynamically it cannot be manually optimized, it is different for each search query.

Answer (score 0):

We can use addQueryHint on Criteria object

```
Criteria c = getCurrentSession().createCriteria(AbcEntiry.class);
c.addQueryHint("first_rows(1500)");
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).