# How to use Oracle query hint in Hibernate

Tags: oracle, hibernate, orm, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-criteria

I am trying to use Oracle hint in Hibernate to call force index, but didn't find any proper API in Hibernate 3.6.10.Final.

I somehow tried with projections in Hibernate criteria:

```
proList.add(Projections.sqlProjection("/*+ INDEX_DESC(CONTACT_USER_FK_I) */", new String[]{}, new Type[]{}));
                proList.add(Projections.property("objectId"));
                criteria.setProjection(proList);
                return criteria.list();
```

But I am getting the exception below:

```
    EXCEPTION
Caused by: 8 SQL Error  (could not execute query; SQL [select /*+ INDEX_DESC(CONTACT_USER_FK_I) */, this_.CONTACT_ID as y0_ from R4GDEV01_MBW.CONTACT this_ w
here this_.USER_ID=? and this_.ADDRESS_BOOK_ID in (?) and this_.DELETION_DATE is null order by lower(this_.FIRSTNAME) asc]; nested exception is org.hibernate
.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query)
        at com.fusionone.pml.dao.hibernate.AbstractDao.executeCallback(AbstractDao.java:391)
        at com.fusionone.pml.dao.hibernate.AbstractContactDao.searchContacts(AbstractContactDao.java:1019)
        at com.fusionone.nab.core.service.impl.MergeServiceImpl.getFilteredContactIds(MergeServiceImpl.java:154)
        ... 91 more
```

I found out that the projection is appending a `,` after query hint.

Is there any other way to use Oracle query hint in Hibernate 3.6.10 criteria or in HQL?

Thanks

Comment: Is there any other way to use Oracle hint instead of hard coding the Index in the code, some thing like can we implement it from hibernate property file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try to search first. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327503/how-to-insert-an-optimizer-hint-to-hibernate-criteria-api-query) is a simple trick to solve this, just *transform* the hint into a column:

```
"/*+ INDEX_DESC(CONTACT_USER_FK_I) */ 1 as MYHINT"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick response, this solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that there is nothing previous to `,`. Due to you want to add a projection on `objectId`attribute, you could transform your criteria to somenthing like this:

```
Projections.sqlProjection("/*+ INDEX_DESC(CONTACT_USER_FK_I) */ objectId", new String[]{}, new Type[]{}))
```

Comment: Thanks i got the issue, is there any other way to use Oracle hint instead of hard coding the Index in the code, some thing like can we implement it from hibernate property file